# How to write unit tests for hibernate domain objects

Tags: java, hibernate, junit4

I have domain objects with one to many, many to many, many to one relations in hibernate. I wrote the unit tests for the validation rules imposed on the domain objects.

To improve the test coverage i have to write test cases for the relations in hibernate domain.

Can any one tell me the best way to cover those ?

Comment: Improving test coverage is not a goal in itself, if that were true, you could just write tests with no `assert`'s. Does it make sense to test your domain objects?

Comment: Thanks, and i agree with what you said. If we keep the test coverage a side, i thought there would be good way of testing the relationship annotations on the domain object.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to test. What kind of bugs would you like your tests to prevent? What would you like your tests to make you more confident about?

Answer (score 0):

I guess domain object do not have any logic as such, which falls into business logic category to test. Yes, but it may happen that the business logic is heavily using the domain object, associated with remote database resource.

Testing with any resource outside JVM is a bit difficult, because the test cases needs to be independent of any resource, like network or database etc.

You may think to use http://www.thedance.net/~roth/TECHBLOG/powerMock.html for testing in such scenario. Also Powermock is much more powerful to let you test number of method calls, testing static code and flow check (Java built in assert, assertNull etc only has really a number of serious limitation).